# How to monitor my processes using monitor package?

Tags: c, linux, fork, monitoring, shared-memory

I have a C code that fork M processes to multiply two M*M Matrices . [ C=A*B ]
each process compute one row , In my code I can compute the time that the process take.
But also I want to monitor my processes using Monitor package.
Here is my code

```
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    pid_t childPID;
    const int M=atoi(argv[1]);
    int shm_fd;
    double* shared_memory;
    const int msize = 3*M*M*sizeof(double);
    const char *name="MATRIX_MULTIPLICATION";

    shm_fd=shm_open(name,O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG);
    ftruncate(shm_fd,msize);
    shared_memory=(double *)mmap(NULL, msize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,  MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);

    double *a=shared_memory;
    double *b=shared_memory+ M*M;
    double *c=b+ M*M;

    populate(M,a,b);
    printf("Done populating\n");

    //fork
    int i;
    long t1,t2,t11,t22;
    t11=clock();
    for(i=0;i<M;i++)
    {
        childPID=fork();
        if(childPID>=0)
        {
            if(childPID==0)
            {
                t1=clock();
                computeRow(M,i,a,b,c);
                t2=clock();
                printf("Time for parallel Multiplication , Row number %d \n",i);
                printf("%ld ms\n",t2-t1);
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    int x=0;
    int stat;
    do
    {
        x=waitpid(-1,&stat,WNOHANG);
    }while(x==0);

    t22=clock();

    printf("It take %ld ms to finish Matrix multiplication using fork and shared_memory \n\n",t22-t11);

shm_unlink(name);
    return 0;
}
```